# How to get MASM assembly working in a Linux .so file

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries, masm

I have somewhat of a unique problem. I have a `.dll` written using VC++ and MASM. (ml64 14.34.31942)

The C part is simply a wrapper so one function can be called by a C# (.net6) application. There is only one entry point, which passes a pointer to a large state object. The function returns a int32 as a result code.

I'd like to get this application working on Linux. I think the C# application will work, but my problem is the calls to the unmanaged `.dll`.

If I take the object file that `ml64.exe` creates, I can wrap it in a C wrapper to set the registers to the calling convention:

*core.c*

```c
#include <stdint.h>

extern int32_t asm_func(void* state);

int wrapper(void *state)
{
  __asm__ volatile(
     "mov %rdi, %rsi \t\n"
     "call asm_func  \t\n");

  return 0;
}

int32_t fnEmulatorCode(void* state) {
  return wrapper(state);
}
```

(return code tbd!)

and compile using: `gcc -shared -o EmulatorCore.so -fPIC core.c core.obj -Wall -g -m64` (core.obj is the MASM object file)

The resulting `.so` file is referenced like any other unmanaged dll:

```cs
    [DllImport(@"./EmulatorCore/EmulatorCore.so")]
    private static extern int fnEmulatorCode(ref CpuState state);
```

And the call works! Kinda of. The entry point is found, and the C wrapper changing the registers is all fine.

However, within the assembler code there are tables of function pointers, which on Linux are not being relocated so a call to the table is seg faulting. This works on Windows.

Eg:

```
lea rax [opcode_00]
lea rax, qword ptr [rax + rbx * 8]  ; rbx is the instruction
jmp qword ptr [rax]                 ; was original jmp qword ptr [rax + rbx * 8]

...

opcode_00   qword   x00_brk         ; $00
opcode_01   qword   x01_ora_indx    ; $01
opcode_02   qword   noinstruction   ; $02
...
```

All other jumps and references seem to be fine.

And suggestions on how to proceed? The object file generated by MASM is `pe-x86-64` according to `objdump`. However `objcopy` doesn't seem to be able to convert this to a `elf64-x86-64`.

So why would Linux not 'relocate' these tables? Is it through some gcc optimisation? Or maybe dotnet isn't loading the library correctly? Or just that the `pe-coff` file doesn't expose them properly? If so, how do I work around?

I can't change the original code from MASM, but is there something that can convert it to NASM or similar so I can cross compile? (Not that Googling finds anything..)

I could probably change the table to a proper 'jump table', but that would hurt performance and there could be other issues, so in the first instance I'd rather try to keep the ASM source as is...

Edit:

using `nm -gC EmulatorCore.so | grep opcode_00` returns nothing, which implies the references aren't included in the `.so` file, so cannot be relocated properly? (The procs in the table do appear, which is why the rest of the app appears to work)

Edit2:

To illustrate the issue, compare these two images. One from Windows which shows the table in the range of where the library is in memory, in Linux the values are all very low, indicating the are an offset from  entry point of the library.

Table in Memory in Windows (RIP: 0x00007FFE043C5817)
[image]

Table in memory in Linux (RIP: 0x00007f24fc59a5a8)
[image: Linux Memory Dump]

Showing the RIP after the jump from the table, showing it is reading the values correctly, its just the values are wrong.
[image]

Comment: I'm out of my depth here, but if I recall correctly, code in the .so has to be position-independent, so you may not be able to do it in Linux the exact same way as you can in Windows.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError same for Windows I thought, its just the code is relocated on load?

Comment: With a quick search for "convert masm nasm" I found http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/faq/converting/asm2s-sed.html , and there seems to be a converter `nomyso` for DOS or FreeBSD.

Comment: @Bodo, That is MASM 32bit, which I think is slightly different, plus the comments say it doesn't support objects, which I use a lot.

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484336/how-to-compile-and-run-assembly-code-in-linux?force_isolation=true  The link on the page so code with following attributes : .386
data segment use16

Comment: @jdweng if you know of a compiler that compiles MASM, that would be great! The application is dotnet 6, so runs nativity on Linux so dosbox isn't really an option.

Comment: Code is running on Window and you are getting a segment fault.  The segment fault I believe is due to alignment.  You are probably exceeding the memory size that compiler assigned to the segment by a few bytes.  You are using qword which is 64 bits and the compiler is 32 bit.  So the linker has to make sure that the 64 bits does not fall out of the segment area.

Comment: Any particular reason this is tagged `C#`?

Comment: @Flydog57 well it could be dotnet not loading the library correctly. Although I do doubt it, so I've removed that tag.

Comment: @jdweng code is fine in windows. Using `gdb` to view the table in memory, its simple offsets, so not relocated as it is when I view the same range of memory on Windows.

Comment: I meant that it is working in Windows so it is not the code.  Since you are compiling in 32 bit mode add to source ALIGN[32] which will make sure the 64 bit word is inside the segment memory area.

Comment: @jdweng I've added pictures showing the pointers are not being updated. Also I am not compiling in 32bit mode. This is a x64 application.

Comment: May the parameter passing is using Window instead of c language. DllImport you can specify the type.  I believe the default is Window.

Comment: @jdweng Parameter passing is handled by the wrapper, and has been verified to be working. The program could not continue to accessing the table without that working.

Comment: If you look closely at the assembly one is 32 bit and the other 64 bit.

Comment: @jdweng I dont understand what you mean by that.

Comment: The second dump has the upper bytes all zeroes.  I think is is 32 bit.  The first dump doesn't have all the zeroes and is 64 bit.  I think it is a linker issue.  See : https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html

Comment: Read following.  It might be clue : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/best-practices#formerly-built-in-supported-types

Comment: You may have on linux a 32 bit kernel even though the micro is 64 bit.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267003/cross-compile-masm-syntax-assembly-with-mingw-on-linux

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253356/discussion-between-bjury-and-jdweng).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows the jump tables are recalculated properly, however on Linux they are not.

In order to get this working the tables needed to be converted to relative jumps and called like this:

```
lea rax [start]
add rax, qword ptr [rax + rbx * 8]  ; rbx is the instruction
jmp qword ptr [rax]                 ; was original jmp qword ptr [rax + rbx * 8]

...

start:
opcode_00   qword   x00_brk         - start ; $00
opcode_01   qword   x01_ora_indx    - start ; $01
opcode_02   qword   noinstruction   - start ; $02
...
```